# Trouble with SUM(IF) condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

Can anyone help me to fix the query below? I need to produce a report that is able to count how many TOB is sent & signed without certain period. There are 3 different TOB tables. Below is my SQL query:

```
select cl.name, con.name,
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tp.sent_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Perm Sent",
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tp.signed_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Perm Signed",
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tt.sent_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Temp Sent",
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tt.signed_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Temp Signed",
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tc.sent_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Contract Sent",
    COUNT(IF(DATE( tc.signed_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0))  as "TOB Contract Signed"
FROM clients cl
    LEFT OUTER JOIN consultants con ON cl.CIC = con.con_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tob_perm tp ON tp.client_id = cl.client_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tob_temp tt ON tt.client_id = cl.client_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tob_contract tc ON tc.client_id = cl.client_id
WHERE cl.status IN(1) and cl.client_id = 16
GROUP BY cl.client_id
order by cl.client_id asc
```

Sample Data:
**Consultants Table**

```
id       name
-----------------
 1       Andy
```

**Clients Table**

```
id       name       con_id
----------------------------
 1     Client A        1
```

**TOB Perm**

```
id       client_id          sent_on          signed_on
-------------------------------------------------------
 1           1            2012-02-05         0000-00-00
 2           1            2012-10-09         2012-06-03
```

**TOB Temp**

```
id       client_id          sent_on          signed_on
-------------------------------------------------------
 1           1            0000-00-00         2012-08-30
 2           1            0000-00-00         2012-02-19
 3           1            2012-10-09         2012-06-03
```

**TOB Contract**

```
id       client_id          sent_on          signed_on
-------------------------------------------------------
 1           1            2012-08-30         0000-00-00
```

Table result that I want to produce is as below:

```
No    Client Name    Consultant     TOB perm sent     TOB perm signed     TOB temp sent       TOB temp signed      TOB contract sent       TOB contract signed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Client A        Andy              2                   1                  1                     3                    1                       0
```

Can anyone help me with my query? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I think there is something wrong with my IF condition:

```
IF(DATE( tp.sent_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31', 1, 0)
```

Is there anyone can help me figure out the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `count` with `sum` to make it work.

`count` counts the records and does not care about conditions. Use for instance

```
SUM(DATE( tp.sent_on ) between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried on SUM before, and it didnt give the right result. is there a problem with the way i write the conditions?

Comment: No, the conditions seem fine. Just use `sum()`

Comment: I tried to use SUM() but the result give me 0, if COUNT() then it will give me 2 for all columns